# Create multiple plots using plotly (plot.ly) in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am attempting to write a function that presents the user multiple plots in a specific order created using plotly. The user is meant to see a plot and then when enter is pressed the next plot is to appear.
Here is a sample function to illustrate the problem:

```
library(plotly)
test_function <- function(){
  set.seed(100)
  n<-100
  x1 <- runif(n)
  y1 <- runif(n)
  x2 <- runif(n,1,3)
  y2 <- runif(n,1,3)

  plot_ly(x= ~x1,y= ~y1,type = "scatter")
  cat("Hit <Return> to see next plot: ")
  line <- readline()
  plot_ly(x= ~x2, y= ~y2, type = "scatter")
}
```

When test_function() is executed, only the last plot is shown.
What can be done to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noticed only the last plot is returned from your function so it is the only one that is printed.

You could just embed both `plotly` calls within `print`:

```
  print(plot_ly(x= ~x1,y= ~y1,type = "scatter"))
  cat("Hit <Return> to see next plot: ")
  line <- readline()
  print(plot_ly(x= ~x2, y= ~y2, type = "scatter"))
```

But a better practice would be to return the plots from the function for example using `list` and organize your function like this :

```
test_function <- function(){
  set.seed(100)
  n<-100
  x1 <- runif(n)
  y1 <- runif(n)
  x2 <- runif(n,1,3)
  y2 <- runif(n,1,3)

  p1 <- plot_ly(x= ~x1,y= ~y1,type = "scatter")
  p2 <- plot_ly(x= ~x2, y= ~y2, type = "scatter")
  list(p1,p2) # return the pair of plot
}


show_plots <- function(l){
  print(l[[1]]) # display plot 1
  cat("Hit <Return> to see next plot: ")
  line <- readline()
  print(l[[2]]) # display plot 2
}

show_plots(test_function())
```